# worst that can happen if i don't obey the stateless custom allocators dogma?

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++11

I need to create a custom allocator for std:: objects (particularly and initially for std::vector) but it might eventually come to use others

The reason I need to create a custom allocator is that I need to track allocated (heap & stack) resources by individual components of the application (*this is an inherent feature of the application*). I will need the custom allocator to monitor the heap portion of the resources, so it is essential that I'm able to pass to the std::vector constructor something like

```
trackerId idToTrackUsage;
myAlloca<int> allocator(idToTrackUsage);
vector<int> Foo( allocator );
```

However, after reading a bit I found this little bomb about the STL / C++ standard (see references) saying that all allocator instances of a given type should be equivalent (that is that == should return true for any two instances) and, most terminal; any allocator should be able to deallocate memory allocated by any other instance (that is, without having a way to know what that other instance might be). In short, allocators cannot have state.

So I'm trying to find the best way around this. Any clever ideas? I really really REALLY don't want to have to keep a custom version of std::vector around.

EDIT: i read about scoped allocators for c++0x on http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#scoped-allocator but i couldn't really get far into understanding how this applies to my problem. If anyone thinks c++0x alleviates this problem, please comment

References:

[Allocator C++ article in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allocator_(C%2B%2B))

[Some random further reading courtesy of Google](http://www.codeguru.com/Cpp/Cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c4079/)

Comment: By the way, somewhat related, but I seem to recall there being significant changes to the allocator model in C++0x. Anyone know anything about this? (Or was this only before Concepts got removed?)

Comment: i read about that on http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#scoped-allocator but i couldn't really get far into understanding how this applies to my problem. (will update post with this)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aside from the obvious answer ("if you violate any requirement, that's undefined behavior, good night and thanks for playing"), I imagine the *worst* that would likely happen, is that the `vector` implementation can rely on the requirement that "all instances of the allocator class are interchangeable" in the obvious way:

```
vector(const Allocator &youralloc = Allocator()) {
    const Allocator hawhaw;
    // use hawhaw and ignore youralloc. 
    // They're interchangeable, remember?
}
```

Looking at the source, GCC's vector implementation (which I think is based eventually on SGI's original STL implementation) does sort-of store a copy of the allocator object passed into that constructor, so there's some hope that this won't happen.

I'd say try it and see, and document what you've done *very carefully*, so that anyone attempting to use your code on an implementation that you haven't checked, knows what's going on. Implementers are encouraged in the standard to relax the restrictions on allocators, so it would be a dirty trick to make it look as though they're relaxed when really they aren't. Which doesn't mean it won't happen.

If you're really lucky, there's some documentation for your container implementation that talks about allocators.

Comment: i added state to the allocator and made sure that the == and != return the correct check based on state, so if its asserted somewhere in the vastness of std sourcecode, it should fail. I've tested for half a month and it seems that it doesn't assert it or needs to check for it, and it's been working great so far, **at least with std::vector**

Comment: @lurscher: Test it with `list` and `map`.  Which take a `Allocator<value>` parameter, but use a `Allocator<node>` underneath.  If it works with that, you're probably fine.

Answer (score 3):

You could, of course, leave a pointer to whatever state you need in any allocated blocks. This does of course mean that any per-block state must be stored in that block, and the allocator instances would act more like handles than actual objects in as of themselves.

Comment: this is an interesting possibility

Answer (score 1):

Making the allocator state static would do the trick, if you're able to work with that. It does mean that all allocators of that *type* will have to share their state, but from your requirements, that sounds like it could be acceptable

Comment: no actually different allocators for different components will have (using my example code) different trackerId, so basically i will be able to do: component A, 15% of heap, component B, 67% of heap, etc.

Comment: @lurscher: and you can't do that by using a separate allocator for each component?

Comment: @lurcsher if you need different allocators you can still use static state but have the allocator a template class which has a unique parameter so you actually have different types and different static data for all instances.

Comment: i would have to allocate a definite number of components at compile-time, one for each template type parameter

Answer (score 1):

To respond to your edit: yes, in C++0x or C++11, allocators can have state.